# Parameter of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (O-U) process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I am considering the following O-U process
$$\mathrm{d}X(t)=-gX(t)\mathrm{d}t+\mathrm{d}B_t$$

From my dataset, I can estimate value of $g$ and it is very small. If covariance of this process is function of $e^{-g\Delta t}$, with the small value of $g$ the decay rate will be slower. Does that mean that the mean reverting rate for my data is weak? Can someone please explain for me the indication of $g$ in this O-U process? Also, if my data has exponential decay covariance over time, can I say that my dataset can be modelled as O-U process?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $g > 0$ is small, then $X(t)$ and $X(t+\Delta t)$ will indeed be relatively more strongly correlated (in the stationary setting). To see this consider the Markov property of the O-U process. In particular, write $X(t+\Delta t)$ in terms of $X_t$.

$$X(t+\Delta t) = e^{-g\Delta t}X_t + \int_t^{t+\Delta t} e^{-a(t+\Delta t - s)}\,dB_s$$

Then you can write (by noting that $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable due to adaptedness and the increments of Brownian motion inside the integral are independent of this sigma algebra)
$$cov(X(t+\Delta t),X_t) = cov(e^{-g\Delta t}X_t + \int_t^{t+\Delta t} e^{-a(t+\Delta t - s)}\,dB_s,X_t) = e^{-g\Delta t}var(X_t) $$

It is a well-known property of the O-U process that $var(X_t) = \frac{1}{2g}(1-e^{-2gt})$. If you can argue that the data you have was collected at large values of $t$ (relative to $g$), then you could say $var(X_t) \sim \frac{1}{2g}$. Hence, $cov(X(t+\Delta t),X_t) = \frac{1}{2g}e^{-g\Delta t}$

This makes sense since if $g$ is small, the part of $X(t+\Delta t)$ that is coming from $X_t$ will have a heavier weight in the composition of $X(t+\Delta t)$.

By looking at the SDE for the O-U process you could also think of $g$ as the spring stiffness in a mechanical system. The larger $g$ is, the more strongly $X$ will be pulled towards $0$ whenever it tries to escape the $0$ level.

Comment: thanks @ Calculon, I also calculated $cov(X(t+\Delta t),X(t))=\frac{1}{2g}e^{-g\Delta t}$. If $g$ is small show the strong correlation between $X(t)$ and $X(t+\Delta t)$ in the stationary setting, then if $\Delta t$ is large enough to make $cov = 0$ , can I say $X(t)$ and X(t+\Delta t) are weakly independent (I have also prove that $X(t)$ follow geometric Brownian motion). I am sorry that I did not fully understand when you mention "more strongly correlated (in stationary setting)".

Comment: @Ocean $X(t)$ does not follow geometric Brownian motion. You may want to take a look at the definition of GBM for that. Stationary setting corresponds to the case where you let $t$ (not $\Delta t$) go to infinity. Then, in the stationary setting $var(X_t) = var(X_{t+\Delta t})$. From this you can see that $corr(X_t,X_{t+\Delta t}) = e^{-g\Delta t}$. If $g > 0$ and $g$ is small, then $g\Delta t$ will be close to $0$. Hence, $corr(X_t,X_{t+\Delta t})$ will be close to 1.

Comment: Thanks @Calculon, I have tested my data and $\log X(t)$ is Gaussian with independent increments, therefore it is Brownian motion. That is why I thought $X(t)$ follows geometric Brownian motion and I hope that I can show if $X(t)$ can be modelled as Ornstein-Uhlenbeck.